Got "unresolved external symbol" in CUDA when using lambda
I was compiling my .cu file with -arch=sm_75 -rdc=true --expt-extended-lambda passed to nvcc (v12.4.99, windows, vs 17 2022). However, I got error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol:
LINK : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_81293256_4_t_cu_2bebb7d5_7784 referenced in function "void __cdecl __nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback(void * *)" (?__nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback@@YAXPEAPEAX@Z) 

The code I was compiling:
template <typename F, typename... Args> __device__ void exec(F f, uint32_t tid, Args &&...args) {
  f(tid, static_cast<Args &&>(args)...);
}

template <typename F, typename... Args> __global__ void kernel(F f, Args... args) {
  uint32_t tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  exec(f, tid, args...);
}

template <uint32_t X, uint32_t Y, typename F, typename... Args> void launch(F f, Args &&...args) {
  kernel<F><<<X, Y>>>(f, static_cast<Args &&>(args)...);
}

int main() {
  launch<4, 4>([] __device__(uint32_t id, uint32_t v) { printf("%u %u\n", id, v); }, 1u);
  return 0;
}

I guess it is caused by -rdc, how can I solve it?

@user14063792468 This syntax is correct for CUDA C++ (a C++ dialect). It is still an unnamed function. It is just marked as function that is supposed to run on the device (a GPU) and not the host (a CPU). See CUDA C++ Programming Guide: Extended Lambdas

The code seems to compile/link/run fine on Compiler Explorer. So maybe this is Windows/Visual Studio specific issue...
